# Determining if motherboard has SAS compatibility and SAS software RAID compatibility?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, sas

What specs are you supposed to look for in a motherboard to determine if it has SAS compatibility and SAS software RAID compatibility built into it?

I'm looking under the details of this:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813128510

And under store devices it shows:

**SATA 6Gb/s**
6 x SATA 6Gb/s

**SATA RAID** 0/1/5/10/JBOD

Can SAS hard drives go plug into the SATA ports?  Do I need a separate hardware RAID controller or does the motherboard support SAS RAID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SATA controllers don't support SAS devices.

SAS controllers often do support SATA devices.

So far as I understand things.

So no, you need a separate SAS RAID controller (or use plain SAS controller + software RAID - usually not recommended)

See [TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/UNIFIED-SERIAL-RAID-CONTROLLERS-PCI-EXPRESS,1665-2.html)

Comment: Also from what I've seen, motherboards that do support SAS will state so explicitly.

Comment: You should look for something that *explicitly states there's an SAS controller*, yes.